# Variance structure with GLMMPQL

Tags: mixed-model, heteroscedasticity, glmm, weights

I want to know the influence of different climate variables on the abundance of berries. I have an average number of berries per plot and a number of plot per site (unbalanced design) for a number of years. Noted that the climate variables are the same for each site.

After doing a backward selection with different climate variables, I created my final model as follow. The theta was found using glm.nb

```
PQL <- glmmPQL(nb ~ yr_7.8t+ yr_11.4p,  ~1 | site/code,
           data = ENIG,family = negative.binomial(theta = 0.478 , link =log))
```

However, when I plot the fitted values against the residual I obtain the following graph where residuals variance increase with fitted values.

[image]

To correct for heteroscedasticity, I would like to modify the variance structure so that it increases with increasing fitted values, I thus specify the argument weight with:

```
VS<- varIdent (form = ~ fitted(.))
```

My new formula is than:

```
 PQL <- glmmPQL(nb ~ yr_7.8t+  yr_11.4p,  ~1 | site/code,
           data = ENIG,family = negative.binomial(theta = 0.478, link = log, weights=VS))
```

but I get the following error code:

```
Error in negative.binomial(theta = 3.222, link = log, weight = VS1) : unused argument (weights = VS1)
```

Why is it not using the argument weight? Is it a problem with my database or one with the formula?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Here is a reproducible example with a subset of my database. I am using R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit), Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

```
library(nlme)
library(MASS)

#The dataset
ENIG <- structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("BL", 
"DL", "IQ"), class = "factor"), code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("BL1", "BL2", "BL3", "BLC", "DL1", "IQ1"), class = "factor"), 
year = c(2011L, 2013L, 2011L, 2013L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2013L, 2010L, 2011L, 2013L, 2008L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L), nb = c(0L, 0L, 15L, 11L, 244L, 
82L, 215L, 57L, 14L, 226L, 4L, 190L, 10L, 133L, 15L, 15L, 
372L, 321L, 507L, 124L), yr_7.8t = c(1.477558128, -0.414880854, 
1.477558128, -0.414880854, -1.943389262, -0.102940362, 1.477558128, 
-0.414880854, -0.102940362, 1.477558128, -0.414880854, -0.371380768, 
0.568656114, 1.137974226, 1.839691899, -0.325040922, 1.334558544, 
1.339717255, -0.393609652, -0.161467655), yr_11.4p = c(0.366571699, 
-0.248137154, 0.366571699, -0.248137154, -0.641320665, 1.202805897, 
0.366571699, -0.248137154, 1.202805897, 0.366571699, -0.248137154, 
-0.260843927, -0.468985372, -0.291086701, 2.431652464, -0.549929268, 
0.186911461, 1.147515783, 0.242623135, 0.135420368)), .Names = c("site", 
"code", "year", "nb", "yr_7.8t", "yr_11.4p"), row.names = c(15L, 
17L, 21L, 24L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 39L, 45L, 48L, 51L, 63L, 66L, 69L, 
72L, 76L, 84L, 87L, 90L, 93L), class = "data.frame")

#glm.nb model to find theta
NB <- glm.nb(nb ~ yr_7.8t+ yr_11.4p, data = ENIG)

#glmmPQL model
PQL <- glmmPQL(nb ~ yr_7.8t+ yr_11.4p,  ~1 | site/code,
           data = ENIG,family = negative.binomial(theta = 0.478 , link =log))

#Make diagnosis plot
plot(fitted(PQL), residuals(PQL), xlab = "Fitted Values", ylab = "Residuals")
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)

#create variance structure
VS <- varIdent (form = ~ fitted(.))

#Refit model with variance structure
PQL <- glmmPQL(nb ~ yr_7.8t+  yr_11.4p,  ~1 | site/plot,
           data = ENIG,family = negative.binomial(theta = 0.478, link = log, weights=VS))
```

Comment: It's not at all clear you have heteroscedastic residuals.  Are you asking about how to improve this model or about how to make your `R` code work?

Comment: I thought for sure I had heteroscedastic residuals... but I might be looking too much at idealized models. The initial model without the variance structure works fine so if I don't need it, my problem is solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your residual plot does not exhibit obvious heteroscedasticity so I would not be concerned by that.

The reason for the error is that you need to use `weights=` and not `weight=`

With your updated code, the problem is that you are passing `weights=` to `negative.binomial()` not to `glmmPQL()` so you need this syntax instead:

`PQL <- glmmPQL(nb ~ yr_7.8t+  yr_11.4p,  ~1 | site/plot, data = ENIG,family = negative.binomial(theta = 0.478, link = "log"), weights=VS)`

Comment: That's great than! Although, I do get the same error message when I use 'weights=' instead of 'weight='.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example on stackoverflow

Comment: I edited my question to add a reproducible example.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you have further questions about R, please ask on stackoverflow, otherwise your question could be closed on here as off-topic.